# How to display the SVG element when it is kept in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem with displaying svg element which is kept inside a js variable. It's a situational need that it is done this way where I am requesting from the backend for the svg that is being kept as a string value. The response from the backend is then kept as such:

```
let svgValue =  "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.6, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 30 30;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <g id="Layer_3">
    </g>
    <path class="st0" d="M1.9,0v30h10.7v-5.5h4.5V30h10.7V0H1.9z M10,22H5.5v-5H10V22z M10,15H5.5v-5H10V15z M10,8H5.5V3H10V8z M17.1,22
    h-4.5v-5h4.5V22z M17.1,15h-4.5v-5h4.5V15z M17.1,8h-4.5V3h4.5V8z M24.2,22h-4.5v-5h4.5V22z M24.2,15h-4.5v-5h4.5V15z M24.2,8h-4.5
    V3h4.5V8z"/>
</svg>
";
```

Having said that, I'd like to use this SVG and display the icon on my page. For the corporate reason, I can't show you the screenshot but basically, I would like to have the value then be tagged to HTML like this:

```
<><div>{svgValue}</div></>
```

I have tried this but for some reason, the icon is not showing. I'm not sure what I did wrong there so if you guys may please let me know what is happening here, that would be great.

edit: additional info: I am also using the React framework. It requests that I add an array. It's a bit fussy but I can't escape this.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this solution but maybe because I am using react, I'm getting this error:       `'react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLSpanElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'`

Comment: If you have a backend endpoint that returns the svg `GET path/to/svg/generating/endpoint` you could try to use `<img src="path/to/svg/generating/endpoint" alt="" />` instead of manually requesting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to display the svg an image using  tag or  tag.
Instead of

```
<div>{svgValue}</div>
```

write

```
<div>
  <img src={svgValue} />
</div>
```